# Get last "block" (pattern) of log file

Tags: sed, grep, scripting, string, tail

my logfile:

```
...
----------
text1
text2
----------
text3
text4
----------
```

And now I want to grep only the last block (between "----------") -> text3/text4

Thank you :-)

Didn't find any solution...

---

Here's a longer sample input:

```
----------
texta
textb
----------
textc
textd
----------
texte
textf
----------
textg
texth
----------
text1
text2
----------
text3
text4
----------
```

Desired output is the last block **only**:

```
text3
text4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
tac file | sed -n '/----------/,/----------/{/----------/b;p}'
text4
text3
```

Comment: Thank you, but if the log file has more entries / blocks, than the output is not only the last block.

Comment: @xyn, what do you mean? Your question says "I want ... only the last block". If you need something else, you should ask a new question.

Comment: @glennjackman that is what xyn wants, but the one-liner above outputs more than just the last block.   It outputs the last block and every 2nd block thereafter (last, 3rd last, 5th last, 7th last, ...).   I added four more blocks and tested that last night, but didn't have time to write an answer.  I'll edit the question and add my longer sample.

Answer (score 1):

use tac to look at the last lines first and then grab the first block, print it, and then quit sed, and tac once more to restore order.

```
$ tac file |
  sed -ne '
     /--/,/--/!d
     //G
     /\n/!{p;d;}
    /\n$/!q
    s/.*/.*/;h
  ' | tac
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve it w/o reversing the lines first, we use Perl to store the inner lines of block in an array @A. Keep discarding the array every time when we are at the beginning of the block. Print the array only at eof.

```
$ perl -ne '
    print(@A), last if eof;
    my $e = /--/ ... /--/; # get location in blk
    $#A=-1, next if $e == 1; # begin blk
    redo if $e =~ /E0/; # end blk
    push @A, $_ if $e; # inner lines of blk
'  file

text3
text4
```